# Advices about data model and partitions in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, nosql

I am wondering if I did the right data model in Cassandra, and I needed some tips about. First, let me show what it could be in a relational database:

[image: SQL data model]

Then, there is the data model I planned to use in Cassandra:

```
CREATE Table Exch(
    exchsymb text,
    stsymb text,
    date int, //format YYYYmmDD
    dataH float,
    dataM float,
    dataL float
    PRIMARY KEY(exchsymb,stsymb,date)
)

CREATE Table Exch_data (
    exchsymb text,
    name text,
    description text,
    PRIMARY KEY(exchsymb)
)

CREATE Table St_data (
    stsymb text,
    name text,
    description text,
    PRIMARY KEY(stsymb)
)

CREATE Table Users (
    UserId int,
    name text,
    password text,
    PRIMARY KEY(UserId) 
)
CREATE Table Users_St (
    UserId int,
    stsymb text,
    value float,
    nbSt int,
    PRIMARY KEY(UserId,stsymb)
)
```

I wanted to know if I did things right, as I made this model with the following points in mind:

- I separated details of `Exch` and `St` in another Partition (respectively `Exch_data` & `St_data`) because most of the time, I will use directly data into `Exch`
- I also separated the list of `St` owned by a user. I through about map, but I couldn't add a value for each of them.
- Minimize the number of partitions to read when I will do some Selects

I hope you could help me about.

**EDIT:**

About queries I will make:

- One is about all the data present on table `Exch` for a particular `St`
- One will be about the complete list of `St` owned by a `User` (`St_data`<>`Users_St`<>`Users`).
- Data present on `Exch_data` & `St_data` doesn't need to be called so much time.

Comment: to know if your model is right, we need to know the query you make

Comment: @Whitefret Most of the time, I will need all the data present on table `Exch`, and also the complete list of `St` owned by a `User` (`St_data`<>`Users_St`<>`Users`). I updated my post as well

Comment: for the first request, you have exchsymb as a partition key, but you need `St` as a partition key if you want to get all `Exch` for a `St`, otherwise you would have to look across all partitions which is really bad.

Comment: for the seconde request, you have the table that give you the list, but there are other models that could fit. I am not sure having some kind of a join is very good in Cassandra though

Comment: Hum, @Whitefret for the first request, I did not well understand: I want to get all `St` into each `Exch`, but you mentioned the opposite.

Comment: Also, for the second, I though this current model could be wrong, but how can I save a list of `stsymb` for each `User` ? Or I could use a list into `Users`instead

Comment: I mix up the 2 requests sorry. So the first one is ok. It depends what you need to query. If you need to find all st by user, why not have a list of st in user, in the contrary, if you need all users for a st, you need that list in st. If you need both, your data is correct but it seems more like a relationnal shema.To have a small hindsight on schema design: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling